# Fusion of two similar document ready with different classes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, function, document-ready

These two document ready works fine, I just want to have them in one.

My goal is to have .flipperfr.click works only on .flip1fr, .flipfr

and .flipperen.click works only on .flip1en, .flipen

because when i put them together .flipperfr.click or .flipperen.click work on

all classes. here is my two js functions:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var $flips = $('.flip1fr, .flipfr ');
$(".flipperfr").click(function() {
var $cur = $(this).next().stop().slideToggle("fast");
$flips.not($cur).stop().slideUp()
});
});


$(document).ready(function() {
var $flips = $('.flip1en, .flipen ');
$(".flipperen").click(function() {
var $cur = $(this).next().stop().slideToggle("fast");
$flips.not($cur).stop().slideUp()
});
});
```

**UPDATE**
It doesn't work but at the beginning I wanted to use a an easy way like :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var $flips = $('.flip1fr, .flipfr '); $('.flip1en, .flipen ');
$(".flipperfr"); $(".flipperen").click(function() {
var $cur = $(this).next().stop().slideToggle("fast");
$flips.not($cur).stop().slideUp()
});
});
```

BECAUSE, only this part is different between the two functions,

```
var $flips = $('.flip1fr, .flipfr '); $(".flipperfr").click(function() {
var $flips = $('.flip1en, .flipen '); $(".flipperen").click(function() {
```

UPDATE2, The problem here is that all works fine but only from one side, when i go the flipperen the other block stay visible, and don't hide like flipperfr. I did something wrong ?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var $flips = $('.flip1fr, .flipfr ');
var $flips = $('.flip1en, .flipen ');
$(".flipperfr, .flipperen").click(function() {
var $cur = $(this).next().stop().slideToggle("fast");
$flips.not($cur).stop().slideUp()
});
});
```

OR

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var 
$flips = $('.flip1fr, .flipfr ');
$flips = $('.flip1en, .flipen ');
$(".flipperfr, .flipperen").click(function() {
var $cur = $(this).next().stop().slideToggle("fast");
$flips.not($cur).stop().slideUp()
});
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps something like this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $flips = {
    fr: $('.flip1fr, .flipfr '),
    en: $('.flip1en, .flipen ')
  }

  $(".flipperfr, .flipperen").click(function() {
    var lang = $(this).hasClass('flipperfr') ? 'fr' : 'en';
    var $cur = $(this).next().stop().slideToggle("fast");
    $flips[lang].not($cur).stop().slideUp();
    // or without $flips
    $('.flip1' +lang + ', .flip' +lang ).not($cur).stop().slideUp();
  });
});
```

Comment: It works fine but why the structure is so different from the two separate  functions ?

Comment: what do you mean different? please show how you were trying to do it that caused problems

Comment: See my question I added something ;)

Comment: Yes I know it was just for the logic, did you see the second part of my update, my logic was based on the two different lines. I thought that i would keep the structure and add only the different part in the first. You understand what I mean ?

Comment: you would have to put `var $flips` inside the click handler to do it that way.

Comment: I tried it but I'm in front of a problem, I explain it on my question via update2

Comment: I will keep your answer, it wasn't my first choice but it works fine ;D thank you so much mister